# Копирование ArrayList

Tags: java, массивы, arraylist

Есть `ArrayList` со значениями.
**Вопрос:** как можно без циклов полностью скопировать значение массива?

```
ArrayList a;
ArrayList b;

a = b;// Присвоить все значения b в этот массив.
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1. Можно с использованием метода [`Collections.copy(destination, source)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#copy%28java.util.List,%20java.util.List%29) (минус в том, что нужно задать `ArrayList b` нужного размера, иначе будет ругаться):

   ```
   Collections.copy(b,a);
   ```
2. С помощью [`clone()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#clone()) (пример на [ideone](http://ideone.com/q56yAk)):

   ```
   ArrayList<String> b = (ArrayList<String>)a.clone();
   ```
3. С помощью конструктора:

   ```
   ArrayList<String> a;
   ArrayList<String> b = new ArrayList<String>(a);
   ```
4. С помощью метода [`addAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#addAll(int,%20java.util.Collection)):

   ```
   ArrayList<String> a;
   ArrayList<String> b = new ArrayList<String>();
   b.addAll(0, a);
   ```

Answer (score 10):

```
ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("abc", "mno"));
ArrayList<String> b;
b = (ArrayList<String>) a.clone();
```

А можно ещё так:

```
ArrayList<String> b = new ArrayList<String>(a);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
ArrayList a;
ArrayList b;

a=b.clone();
```

Answer (score 1):

В листе хранятся ссылки на объекты, поэтому копируются именно они, т.е. через новый лист вы по факту работаете со старыми объектами. если хотите перенести скопировать значения, то сначала вам нужно создать новый объект для хранения значения при помощи оператора `new`.

Например:

```java
ArrayList<String> toCopy = new ArrayList<>();

toCopy.add("Something");

ArrayList<String> copy = new ArrayList<>();

copy.add(new String(toCopy.get(0)));
```