# Копирование ArrayList в двумерный ArrayList в Java

Tags: java, arraylist

Как можно скопировать ArrayList в ArrayList> ?
Например:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> k = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> m = new ArrayList<>();
m.add("m1");
m.add("m2");
m.add("m3");
m.add("m4");
```

Теперь m нужно скопировать в k.
k.add(m) - не подходит, т.к. ссылки на значения m при m.clear() будут удалены и из k.
Варианты, указанные в [Копирование ArrayList](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/561374/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-arraylist/561383) - реализовать не удается, т.к. не удается адресоваться к конкретному "внутреннему" ArrayList.
Как можно такое копирование осуществить?

Comment: `не удается адресоваться к конкретному "внутреннему" ArrayList` а как вы хотите к нему адресоваться ( где-то почесался `Map<>`)?

Comment: мне нужно сделать что-то вроде: k.get(0) = new ArrayList<String>(m);

Comment: Если индекс последовательный, то что мешает `k.add(m.clone()); k.get(k.size() -1)?` А если произвольный то `Map<> map = ...; map.put(var_index, m.clone()); map.get(var_index);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если я вас правильно понял, можно так

```
k.add( new ArrayList<>(m) );
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!!! Все работает

Comment: А как можно было бы произвести копирование в конкретный элемент ArrayList. Т.е. как, при копировании, указать индекс элемента, в который нужно скопировать?

Comment: @3asys метод set https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set(int,%20E)

Comment: Проблема с методом set в том, что при указании конкретного индекса (например,   k.set(0, new ArrayList<String>(m)); 
) элемента с этим индексом в момент исполнения еще не существует, и выдается ошибка "java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0". Можно конечно предварительно заполнять arraylist пробелами и потом в уже существующие элементы вставлять нужное, но может можно, как-то проще это сделать?

Comment: Можете создать не ArrayList а например TreeSet и написать компаратор как сортировать ваши объекты, а после сделать из него лист.

Comment: По ходу программы я добавляю в ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> отдельные ArrayList<String>. Мне важно, чтобы они добавлялись в элементы с определенными индексами, т.к. это используется в процессе исполнения. Т.е. при добавлении, мне нужно сразу указать элемент и знать, что добавленное в нем и храниться. Сортировка создает отложенный процесс и все сильно усложняется.

Comment: Все оказалось просто: k.add(index, new ArrayList<>(m)); где index - индекс позиции в k в которую нужно вставить m.

Answer (score 1):

Проще всего если закинуть создав новую коллекцию

```
k.add(new ArrayList<String>(m));
```

или склонировать

```
k.add((ArrayList<String>)m.clone());
```